# css-bootstrap- How to make responsive images in a row

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is an image of what I need :
[image]

as you can see, the width of the second image is much bigger that others . it's from a responsive website though .

This is my code and what I've got so far by using bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="4.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <img src="4.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="4.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
</div>
```

the result :
[image]

as you can see, each image's height is different . the widths are good but the height are not in-line .

What should I do to get something like the first image ?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap each `img` in a `span`:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <span class="img-responsive-wrap">
        <img src="4.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Then add CSS something like this:

```
.img-responsive-wrap {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It's not working properly ,when I make the browser smaller ,it only shows about 200px height for each image and the rest of image is not showing .

Answer (score 1):

From the first example it's a 3-6-3 grid, and on mobile probably 12-6-6. To accomplish this I would recommend to alter (crop) the images so they have the right aspect ratio. It's one minute work, and you won't need to use overflow:hidden. I am pretty sure that's what they did in the first example.

Comment: thanks for reply, could you give me an example ,I didn't get you exaclty

Answer (score 0):

Try this, see the code in jsfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/zj9v81t7/15/

```
.row {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.col-md-3{width:28.5%; float:left;}
.col-md-4{width:28.5%; float:left;}
.col-md-5{width:43%; float:left;}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , but this is not a responsive website . I've used this code before, the problem it becomes smaller or bigger on different browser size , the responsive website doesn't do that , it move items after each other and keep the size as it is